# how to add custom validation and message in laravel nova for one field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I want to add custom validation for one field in laravel nova resource file.

I have one field in db which is `service_id` in the `service` table and I have nova resource file for the same table. On create service I want to get data using `service_id` from other table  and check data is present or not and if present then I don't want to enter that `service_id` in table.

So can someone help me how can I write custom validation rules in laravel nova resource file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following command, you can create a custom rule class:

```
php artisan make:rule CustomRule
```

Inside the fields function in your resource:

```
Text::make('Service ID', 'service_id')->rules(new CustomRule());
```

Go back to your rule file and inside the passes function:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    //You can check inside the database if your record exists
    return false; //if the rule should stop the user
    return true; //if everything is fine and you want the user to proceed.
}

public function message()
{
    return 'Return your custom error message';
}
```